# Object TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, mongoose

I want to send data from a form in VueJS with Axios.
But i don't know how to write my object before send it

**View :**

```
    methods: {
    createPost() {
      let autorData = {
        nom: this.nom,
      }
      let postData = {
        titre: this.titre,
        auteur: autorData,
        contenu: this.contenu,
      };
      this.__submitToServer(postData);
    },
    __submitToServer(data) {
      axios.post(`${server.baseURL}/post/create`, data).then(data => {
        router.push({ name: "home" });
      });
    }
  }
```

**Controller :**

```
    import { Controller, Get, Res, HttpStatus, Param, Post, Body, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { PostService } from './post.service';
    import { CreatePostDTO } from './dto/create-post.dto';

    @Controller('post')
    export class PostController {
        constructor(private readonly postService: PostService) { }

        ...

        @Post('/create')
        async addPost(@Res() res, @Body() createPostDTO: CreatePostDTO) {
            const post = await this.postService.addPost(createPostDTO);
            return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
                message: "Post has been created successfully",
                post
            })
        }
    }
```

**Model : CreatePostDTO**

```
    import { User } from 'src/user/interfaces/user.interface';

    export class CreatePostDTO {
        readonly titre: string;
        readonly auteur: User;
        readonly contenu: string;
    }
```

**Model : interface User**

```
    export interface User extends Document {
        readonly nom: string;
    }
```

How can I make it understand that's the "author" data is a sub-object of my "post" ?

**EDIT**

**Error from the server**

```
    ValidationError: Post validation failed: auteur: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "{}" at path "autor"
                  ...
                  at PostService.addPost (C:\Users\me\Desktop\Try\VueJS_NestJS_MongoDB\diy\customer-list-app-backend\src\post\post.s          at C:\Users\yann.surzur\Desktop\Try\VueJS_NestJS_MongoDB\diy\customer-list-app-backend\src\post\post.controller.ts:19:71
                message: 'Cast to ObjectID failed for value "{}" at path "autor"',        name: 'CastError',
                stringValue: '"{}"',
                kind: 'ObjectID',
                value: {},
                path: 'autor',
                reason: [MongooseError] } },
          _message: 'Post validation failed',
          name: 'ValidationError'
```

The problem is there : 'Cast to ObjectID failed for value "{}" at path "autor"'.
That's why i think i made a mistake when i wrote the data before sent it.

Comment: What errors are you getting and where?

Comment: I edited, the problem is that when my server try to cast my data, author is empty and can't be cast